# Is the barycenter of a simplex invariant under affine trasformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, affine-geometry, simplex

While reading Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* chapter $13$, about the subdivision operator in homology, I realized that the author only defines the barycenter of a $p-$simplex $\sigma=[v_0,\dots,v_p]$ as the only point $b_\sigma$ in its interior such that all its barycentric coordinates are equal, that is

$$b_\sigma=\sum_{i=0}^p\frac{1}{p+1}v_i$$

And then, if $\alpha:\Delta_p\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a singular affine simplex (that is, an affine map from the standard $p-$simplex of $\mathbb{R}^p$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$), instead of defining the barycenter of $\alpha$, he works with $\alpha(b_p)$ (where $b_p$ denotes the barycenter of the standard $p-$simplex in $\mathbb{R}^p$). My questions are the following;

- The image of a simplex under an affine transformation is always another simplex?
- Isn't the image of the barycenter of a simplex the same as the barycenter of its image?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The answer is YES, granted that the images of the vertices are linearly independent. Thus, this is a YES for affine injections (hence affine isomorphisms).

Comment: But in general, an affine simplex does not have to send the vertices of the standard simplex to affinely independent points in $\mathbb{R}^n$... so?

Comment: The definition of simplex that you gave does not seem to imply that the vertices are affinely independent.

Comment: My main concern is with affine transformations that don't preserve affine independence... can we find, for example, an affine map that deforms, lets say, a $p-$simplex into a line segment, carrying the barycenter of the first into some point of the second, that is not its middlepoint?

Comment: When you think that it should be the middlepoint, you are forgetting that what you see is not a line segment, it is a singular $p$-simplex.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, Well, that's the point; the image of a singular affine simplex should be a regular simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so again, is the barycenter of the image equal to the image of the barycenter?

Comment: I answered that already below : yes. Simply, you need to not get fooled by the fact that the actual dimension of the image is not relevant. You need to keep track of all the vertices even if there is some overlap.

Comment: I see that those simplicial complexes are not geometric, they are continuous images of geometric complexes. Then the images of barycentric centers are quite a bit arbitrary. You can still prove things, especially when the map of a geometric complex is "nice".

Comment: @WlodAA Not quite; when a $p-$simplex is affine, we are specifically talking about the only affine transformation that sends the points $e_0,\dots,e_p$ or $\mathbb{R}^p$ to $p$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, although they need not be affinely independent, or even distinct.

Comment: @Akerbeltz, sure, but then there are complications. The image of, say 3-simplex may have a 2-simplex as its image while one original vertex may fall anywhere. Then the image of the original barycenter will not be the barycenter of that 2-simplex. The thing would need explicit combinatorial subdivisions, quite a bit removed from the naive geometric image-complex.

Comment: @WlodAA Why would the barycenter fall anywhere? I think the explaination of Arnaud is quite satisfactory, and would contradict your assertion.

Comment: I see your point now. Make it into an answer, and I will accept it soon.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that

> An affine transformation preserves all affine combinations, in the sense that $$f\left(\operatorname{Bar}(\alpha_i, P_i)\right )=\operatorname{Bar}(\alpha_i, f(P_i))$$
>   whenever $\sum \alpha_i=1$.

As a result, the answer to both questions is YES, since

- A simplex is the convex hull of its vertices, and the convex hull is by definition the set of all affine combinations with non-negative coefficients.
- The barycentre is the only affine combination with equal weights.

Comment: Just a simple question about your terminology; what does $\text{Bar}(\alpha_i,P_i)$ represent?

Comment: @Akerbeltz The barycentre of some points $P_i$ with coefficients $\alpha_i$.